# Saving and retrieving value in hook_node_form_alter()

Tags: nodes, forms

This is in Drupal 7.

I have managed to add a section to the node vertical tab. But I have not found out how to save the value and retrieve the value. After saving the node if i go back to the node edit form it still shows the default value. What am I missing?

```
function myModule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['test_settings'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset', 
    '#title' => t('test settings'), 
    '#weight' => 0, 
    '#collapsible' => TRUE, 
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    '#group' => 'additional_settings',
   );

   $form['test_settings']['node_uaid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('uaid'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('node_uaid', "default"),
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxlength' => 50,
    '#description' => t('test UAID.'),
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#group' => 'settingsform'
   );
}
```

The final objective is a field in the node add/edit vertical form that is directly associated with that node. This field should be accessible in relation to the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike building a settings form in Drupal using [`system_settings_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_settings_form/7.x), you need to do more than define the form field so that it's processed. You need to define a submit handler so your custom field can be processed. In your `hook_form_alter()` add a submit handler:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'myModule_form_node_form_submit';
```

Then define your submit handler to process the form value for saving.

```
function myModule_form_node_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  variable_set('node_uaid', $form_state['values']['node_uaid']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking all over drupal.org for a tutorial on this and there is nothing. Some one should really build a good tutorial on drupal.org for stuff like this.

Comment: its showing the value but the problem is now its showing that value for every node. How can this value be associated with the node? If i have two nodes one with value-a and the other with value-b

Comment: You should ask this as a different question (Drupal Answers frowns on back-and-forth commentary of multiple questions). I'll leave one last comment.  You need to save a unique variable (e.g. `'node_uaid_'.$nid`) to do this. Depending on your needs it might make more sense as a field or DB table entry.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was implied that if i'm adding a field to the node add/edit form that i want to associate that field with that node. I can't see any situation where some one would want a field on the add/edit node form that is not associated with the node. The objective is that this field should be associated with the node. I will update my question to better express that this field should be associated with the node.